# How do I Rescale a character

Tags: rigging

I want to make a bunch a similar characters with varying body types. I figure to go in pose mode and modify the bones then duplicate the distorted body mesh. Just that I can't figure out what to do with the bones.

How do I make the modified scaled/translated/rotated bones to become the Rest Position pose and reset transform scale/rotate values?

Comment: https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27351

Other site says to do this but I don't see any Pose button.



       Pose > Apply > Apply Pose as rest Pose